# Differentiating quick-contact and full-contact in a website design

Tags: website-design, usability, forms

I am designing a commercial website which is very elegant,
thinking about adding a quick "sliding" contact form with the essential fields,
to be available in all pages of the site,
in addition to my "full" contact form in the contact page.

I want to call-to-action for both forms in all pages (long pages) and i have a "sign-up to newsletter" also.

Dont want to cause a mess design-wise and not to confuse anyone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the point of creating two different contact forms for your users ? If you haven't already did it, you should ask yourself this question before trying to find a design solution to do this.

Comment: Why are you creating two contactforms? If one is just an extensive version of the other, maybe you could achieve the same thing by making some of the fields invisible. However, this is an anti-pattern, so be very careful.

Comment: I would argue that there is never a reason to provide a "full contact" form on a website.  The purpose of a contact form is to get just enough information for the company to be able to get the client (or potential) on the phone.  Generally speaking, it should just be name, phone, email and a box to type something in.  Every field you add to the form results in fewer people wanting to fill it out.

Answer (score 3):

[I would NOT use two different contact forms.](http://goodui.org/#3)

Hearing you talk about a "quick and easy" contact form accessible on every page in addition to the "full" (a.k.a not quick and easy) contact form makes me ask the question,

**Why wouldn't users *always* want the quick and easy option?**

[image]

Comment: Just a side-note, the UX on the site you link to is awful. Whilst the point may be valid, I have an issue in accepting advice from a site that has a 'wiggling' "subscribe here" floating at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The more *sensible* places that an item exists in the site IA, the more likely it is that a user will be able to find that item.

If you've discovered that there is some group of users who can't find your standard "long" contact form. Then creating a second form and putting that somewhere else on the site that they're more likely to find is an eminently sensible idea.

**So long as you've identified a clear UX need**, adding your sliding "contact us" element sounds like a great plan.

If on the other hand, you haven't got any evidence that users are having trouble finding your other form, then there's no UX reason to put the second one in.

Answer (score 0):

There should ***never*** be a conflict between these two calls to action. If there is, you're doing something wrong.
The only reason to include a second CTA to the same form is if the first CTA is not being clicked.
There can be a whole host of reasons for this, examples include;

1. First CTA is in the header, the user is scrolling down a long page and can no longer action it. Legitimate reason to include a second CTA further down the page or in some other persistent location (sticky margin CTA)
2. The first CTA is poorly designed, or in a poor location, poorly contrasted with site design, poor action text, or any other reason users are not actioning your button. This example needs consideration of the **primary** call to action, rather than adding a **duplicate** CTA.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve information persistence across pages and gain even more flexibility in linking to important parts of the website, why not consider a more creative use of the footer. below is an idea:

[image]

> This is an excellent idea, because it allows users to contact you
>   without having to navigate to the contact page.
>
> source: [Informative And Usable Footers In Web Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/17/informative-and-usable-footers-in-web-design/)

For inspiration your could also see ["Footers In Modern Web Design: Creative Examples and Ideas"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/04/08/footers-in-modern-web-design-creative-examples-and-ideas/)